Haloarenes reactivity in $S_{N}Ar$ being slower due to repulsions between nucleophile and aromatic ring
It is a well-known fact that haloarenes are very slow towards nucleophilic substitution. However, one of the reasons is that there may be electron-electron repulsions between an incoming nucleophile and the aromatic ring which is rich in electrons. Doesn't the halogen atom (which is majorly inductively withdrawing and only weakly participating in resonance in this case) reduce the electron density in the aromatic ring? Why the repulsion then?
Side note: When do we consider the phenyl group's "electron withdrawing" inductive effect? Is that in any way related to this?

There's also a double bond character in the C-X bond as a consequence of resonance. Hence it's difficult to break and is a major reason for the slow reaction.

Yes, but I'm looking for the reasoning for that particular "repulsions" statement.
Of course, the phenyl cation is not stable in any way and the halobenzene is stablised by resonance as you mentioned.

There is no phenyl cation in SN ar. Look at the mechanism and you will know how a halogen molecule at the para position will favour the reaction. A nitro group is even better!


First, there is a partial double bond character in the $C-X$ bond which makes it stronger and hence the halogen becomes a bad leaving group.

Bad leaving group promotes $(S_N)_1$ but a Carbocation is formed which is unstable as the carbon is $sp$ hybridised after the halogen has left making it very electronegative and hence the Carbocation is unstable.

Even if $(S_N)_2$ path is followed then the bulky phenyl group will cause hindrance and also repel the nucleophile as both are electron rich and $(S_N)_2$ requires strong nucleophile. Also during the Transition state in $(S_N)_2$ the attacked Carbon is $sp^2$ hybridised. In this there will be a very high angle strain as benzene will have to retain its aromaticity and the angle between the bonds of that carbon will not be $120°$


Hence the repulsion factor, the steric hindrance factor as well as the hybridization factor and the partial double bond  makes haloarenes slower and less reactive in nucleophilic substitution reactions.

It was modified it asked for SN yesterday lol
